# How Can use External Battery for 3 Pin Fan and control the fan using Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

i am using arduino mega to control the fan. so How Can use External Battery for 3 Pin Fan and control the fan using Arduino Mega.

Comment: Question on how to wire hardware are off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like an electronics design question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you have three wires, there are two wires to be connected with the battery, and the third one to connect with the Arduino so you can control it.

You have to connect the + wire and the - wire with the battery.

Connect the control wire with the Arduino.